# Output different string depending on boolean

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this small piece of code:

```
public DisabledStudent(int id, int age, bool requiressupport)
{
this.requiressupport = requiressupport;
}
```

The array is similar to this below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
const int MaxStudents = 4;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Student[] studentList;
 studentList = new Student[4];

 studentList[0] = new Student(51584, 17);
 studentList[1] = new Student(51585, 19);
 studentList[2] = new Student(51586, 15);
 studentList[3] = new Student(51587, 20);

    for (int i = 0; i < MaxStudents; i++)
    {
         lstStudents.Items.AddRange(studentList);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is output a string from an array of students and basically display a different part of text depending on whether the `requiressupport` boolean is `true` or `false`:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("Disabled Student - ID: {0} (Age {1})", this.Number, this.Age);
}
```

I want that statement above to basically say `Disabled Student - ID: 45132 (Age 19) with support` if the `requiressupport` boolean is `true` and `Disabled Student - ID: 45132 (Age 19) without support` if the `requiressupport` boolean is `false`, but I'm not sure how I'd go about this?

Answer (score 2):

One of your many options is to use the [?: conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("Disabled Student - ID: {0} (Age {1}) {2}", this.Number, this.Age, this.requiressupport ? "with support" : "without support");
}
```